# What is wrong with this buffer overflow solution in c?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I was just marked down on coursework for this incorrect solution to a buffer overflow in c but was not provided feedback on how it was wrong. Could somebody let me know what the problem is? Thank you.

The question stated to provide a solution in case a longer string than 16 was passed in to this function:

```
void function(char *str)
{
    char buffer[16];
    strcpy(buffer, str);
}
```

And here is my solution

```
void function(char *str)
{
    size_t str_length = strlen(str);

    char buffer[str_length];
    strcpy(buffer, str);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your solution also relies on variable length arrays, which were not available until C99. It's possible that the instructor is not aware that they are allowed now.

Answer (score 12):

You need to account for the null character terminating the string:

```
char buffer[str_length + 1];
```

Void_ptr points out that the above is not enough. So to be more robust:

```
void function(char *str)
{
    size_t str_length = strlen(str);
    char *buffer = malloc(str_length + 1);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return;
    memcpy(buffer, str, str_length+1); // Thanks chux
    // Do something with with buffer...
    free(buffer);
}
```

Or maybe the professor was simply looking for this:

```
void function(char *str)
{
    char buffer[16];
    strncpy(buffer, str, sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Still looks kinda unsafe. 1) `buffer` is allocated on the stack - what if you get stack overflow? 2) There's no upper limit on `str_length` - what if there's no terminating 0 for gigabytes and gigabytes of memory space?

Comment: Code paid the price to calculate the length of `str`.  `strcpy()` effectively does that again.  Instead of `strcpy(buffer, str);`, consider the more efficient `memcpy(buffer, str, str_length+1)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are allowed to use but I guess the safest way would be to use strdup and check if it has returned NULL.

```
void function(char *str)
{
    char *buffer;

    buffer = strdup(str);
    if (!buffer)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    free(buffer);
    /* free buffer or keep track of it or you'll end up with memory leaks */
}
```

In the case where you're not allowed to dynamically allocate memory, the use of strncpy is still a more secure alternative to strcpy.

```
void function(char *str)
{
    size_t str_length = strlen(str);
    char buffer[str_length + 1]; /* /!\ This is C99 */

    strncpy(buffer, str, str_length);
    buffer[str_length] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: 1) `strncpy(buffer, str, str_length); buffer[str_length] = '\0';` serves no additional security.  Just use `memcpy(buffer, str, str_length+1);`  2) There is no limit to the size of `buffer[]` - now _that_ is a stack smashing security issue.